# CSS Awesome Font icon as submit button

Tags: html, css

I have a submit button like so:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
```

and I also have this awesomefont icon

```
<i class="fa fa-search"></i>
```

I tried adding the class to the submit button, but that did not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you are dead set on using `<input>`, using a `<button>` makes this quite a bit easier, but it is possible using the unicode version of search and prepending that with `&#x`:

```css
#submitButton {
  font-family: FontAwesome;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<input type="submit" value="&#xf002" id="submitButton">
<button id="submitButton">
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
</button>
```

The Unicode version of any Font Awesome icon can be found just below the icon on the [Font Awesome site](https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/):

[image: Unicode for Font Awesome icons]

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ryanpcmcquen/p0vx0Lxo/)

Answer (score 3):

What about using a button?

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton" />
  <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Submit
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following - use button instead of input and the following code:

```
<button type="submit" id="submitButton">
    <i class="fa fa-search"></i> Submit
</button>
```

Comment: Did you just copy my answer?

Comment: I am sorry this happened, but no, was doing this within codepen and didn't see that you answer was posted, but  just posted my solution inside.

Comment: I will make sure I refresh the answers next time, before posting my own answer.